Firestore .where + Filter.and queries not working
I'm trying to perform a compound and Firestore query in Kotlin by following this guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_and_queries

My code is as follows:
val query =
    Firebase.firestore
        .collection("profiles")
        .where(
            Filter.and(
                Filter.inArray("profileGender", preferenceGenderArray),
                Filter.equalTo("profilePaused", false)
            )
        )
        .get()

Android Studio is giving me these errors in the IDE before I can run this:

Cannot access 'where': it is package-private in 'CollectionReference'
Filter.and can only be called from within the same library (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore)
Filter.inArray can only be called from within the same library (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore)
Filter.equalTo can only be called from within the same library (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore)

In my build.gradle(app) I have implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx
What am I doing wrong here?

As long as you're using the correct dependencies and the following imports:
import com.google.firebase.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Filter
import com.google.firebase.firestore.firestore

Your query should work.

I'm trying to perform a compound and Firestore query in Kotlin.

If you only want to create an and query, according to the official documentation regarding compound (AND) queries, there is no need to use a Filter with an and condition, you can simply use:
val query =
    Firebase.firestore
        .collection("profiles")
        .whereIn("profileGender", preferenceGenderArray)
        .equalTo("profilePaused", false)
        .get()

For which you should create an index.

Seems as though I was using an older module.
I was using implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
I upgraded to implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2"))
Then migrated to using the Kotlin extensions (KTX) APIs in the main modules per this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/kotlin-migration#ktx-apis-to-main-how-to-migrate
So using implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore' instead of implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
